# Upload a WAV file with Paperclip and store both .wav and .mp3 versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mp3, paperclip, wav

I have a Rails application where people can use an in browser sound editor to create wav files and upload them to the server.

I use Paperclip for handling the sound file upload.

I would like to be able to convert the wav file to an mp3, but keep both files.

I have read about Paperclip processors, but I'm not sure how to use them to get both files instead of just converting to mp3 only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, this probably isn't optimal but it works pretty well. I ended up adding another attachment to my `Sound` class for the mp3, and added a `before_validation` filter to hook into it. In addition, since I had some existing wav attachments, I created a `reconvert_to_mp3` method to handle the migrating of the existing records.

```
has_attached_file :mp3,
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => "sounds/:id/:style.:extension"

before_validation :convert_to_mp3

def reconvert_to_mp3
  wavfile = Tempfile.new(".wav")
  wavfile.binmode

  open(wav.url) do |f|
    wavfile << f.read
  end

  wavfile.close

  convert_tempfile(wavfile)
end

def convert_to_mp3
  tempfile = wav.queued_for_write[:original]

  unless tempfile.nil?
    convert_tempfile(tempfile)
  end
end

def convert_tempfile(tempfile)
  dst = Tempfile.new(".mp3")

  cmd_args = [File.expand_path(tempfile.path), File.expand_path(dst.path)]
  system("lame", *cmd_args)

  dst.binmode
  io = StringIO.new(dst.read)
  dst.close

  io.original_filename = "sound.mp3"
  io.content_type = "audio/mpeg"

  self.mp3 = io
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `dst.unlink` at the bottom? Or would that delete the file before Paperclip can grab it?

Comment: @daniel Thanks for the solution its working great. But i am facing some issue in production mode. Error is as follows: `Error reading headers in mp3 input file ` Could you please help me with this? Thanks a lot.